# Model popup not popping as expected

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, css

I have two model popup windows in my project. When i clcik a search button first modul popup will popp in the window. This model popup have option to view details. When i click on it i need another popup to pop and show details.
Now problem is when i click on the view option the second popup is coming behind first popup and  its not visible.
What may be the mistake i have done

```
   if (e.CommandName.Equals("View"))
            {
                ModalRearrangement.Show();
                ModalViewDocument.Show();
            }
```

In the above code **ModalRearrangement** is the first popup.

**Update**

**CSS**

```
  .modalBackground
    {
        background-color: Black;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60);
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
    .modalPopup
    {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        width: 300px;
        border: 3px solid #3CB371;
        border-radius: 12px;
        padding:0

    }
    .modalPopup .header
    {
        background-color: #2FBDF1;
        height: 30px;
        color: White;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-top-left-radius: 6px;
        border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    }
    .modalPopup .body
    {
        min-height: 50px;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .modalPopup .footer
    {
        padding: 6px;
    }
```

This is common css for both popup.

Comment: you have to set both popups z-index

Comment: No,where should i do it css?

Comment: yes main divs of popups

Comment: but my popup are not inside a div.

Comment: why down? I am having doubt with this, so i asked it. Is this question not a genuine one :( ?

Comment: i am not the one who downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Add This To your HTML in Popup `Div`

Give `z-index : 990` To First Pop up
And  `z-index : 9990` To Second Pop up

Comment: But i didn't include popup in a div.

Comment: then give css to modelpop.